# Value between 0 and 1 should become value between x and y

Tags: java, math

Lets say I generate a random number between 0 and 1, 0 should equal a predefined x and 1 should equal a predefined y.

So if I take 2 as my x, and 10 as my y.

When I randomly generate 0.5, the result should be 6.

Is there a way to program this? Sorry for my vague description of my question.

Comment: In rough, mathy, pseudo-ish code: `f(r) = x + r * (y - x)`.

Comment: Java's most important random implementations (java.util.Random, java.security.SecureRandom and java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom) all provide an upper bound. You should be able to meet your requisites with that tool and some basic algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you want to scale the number between two others and then add the minimum:

```
0 <= x <= 1

// Sample values
float x = 0.32
int minimum = 50
int maximum = 65

int difference = maximum - minimum
float result = (difference * x) + minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate numbers from min to max (including both) you can use something like

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rand;
random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
```

Check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)).

If you are using java 1.7 or later you can also use:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```

Comment: I'm not sure he want to necessarily randomly generate the result, only the initial number.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi It is not clear in the question. May be you are right